# apache hama on EC2 through whirr 0.8

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, apache-whirr, hama

I am trying to take a look at Apache Hama and I followed the instructions at http://hama.apache.org/hama_on_clouds.html and downloaded whirr 0.8.2 but in this version there is not any hama-ec2.properties in the folder recipes, therefore i cannot try it.

Is there a reason why this file was removed in this release and there is an alternative on how to try hama through whirr on EC2.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the file `recipes/hama.properties`

The options that you care are the following:

```
#
# Customise instance types & AMI for Amazon EC2
#
#
# Use a specific instance type. See http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
whirr.hardware-id=c1.xlarge
#
# Ubuntu 10.04 LTS Lucid. See http://cloud.ubuntu.com/ami/
whirr.image-id=us-east-1/ami-35de095c
#
# You can also specify the spot instance price: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot-instances/
# whirr.aws-ec2-spot-price=0.15
```

Also, if make sure your setup your credentials file `~/.whirr/credentials` and add these lines to it.

```
PROVIDER=aws-ec2
IDENTITY=<YOUR AWS ACCESS KEY ID>
CREDENTIAL=<YOUR AWS SECRET ACCESS KEY>
```